# Ext.Map within a Ext.Panel

Tags: google-maps, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a panel and want to place a map (Google maps) within it. Is this possible?

When I open my maps page directly it works fine but when I put it in a panel I only get a blank white page without a maps view.

My Panel class:

```
Ext.define("app.view.TodoMaps", {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
requires: "app.view.GoogleMaps",
alias: "widget.todomapscard",


config: {
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    items: [{
        docked: 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        ui: "light",
        title: 'Maps page',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: "button",
                ui: "back",
                text: "back",
                action: 'ButtonBackToHomeClicked'
            }]
    },
        {
            xtype: "googlemapscard"       <----------
        }
    ]
}
});
```

My Map class:

```
Ext.define("app.view.GoogleMaps", {
extend: 'Ext.Map',
alias: "widget.googlemapscard",


//geo: geo, //Ext.util.Geolocation object
//useCurrentLocation: geo, //same var geo with geolocation object
config: {
    mapOptions:{
        zoom: 15,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        //--Available Map Options--//


        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false
    }


}
});
```

How can I achieve that the map is visible within a panel.

PS. the reason I need a panel is because I want to navigate back to the previous panel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after adding **layout: 'fit'** to panel class.